# Python reverse sublist of multi dimensional list

Tags: python, list, reverse

I have the following list:

```
list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

How can I reverse each sublist? i.e

```
list = [[2, 1], [4, 3], [6, 5]]
```

Comment: Don't name a variable `list`; it shadows the built-in type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[sublist[::-1] for sublist in outerlist]
```

Demo:

```
>>> outerlist = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> [sublist[::-1] for sublist in outerlist]
[[2, 1], [4, 3], [6, 5]]
```

This produces a *new* list. You can also reverse sublists in place by calling the `list.reverse()` method on each one in a loop:

```
for sublist in outerlist:
    sublist.reverse()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm a fan of one liners :)

Answer (score 1):

The comprehension and slice syntax is great, but if you want the result to happen in-place with the same outer list, I suggest this might be more readable:

```
for elem in outerlist:
    elem.reverse()
```